# ng-model: empty strings should be null

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I use `ng-model` for an input field and empty it, angular sets it to `''` instead of `null` even if it was `null` before.

This is a problem in my case because I need to send `null` to the server if the input field is empty, and not `''`.

Is there a way to tell angular setting "empty" input models to `null`?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You may want to `$watch` for the empty value and set it to `null`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test.value" />
```

```
$scope.$watch('test.value', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  if(newValue === "")
    $scope.test.value = null;
});
```

Another way would be to use a custom directive and apply a `$parsers` in it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="test.value" empty-to-null />
```

```
myApp.directive('emptyToNull', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                if(viewValue === "") {
                    return null;
                }
                return viewValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Ok, you may configure the scope as isolated in the directive to have a better encapsulation.

Comment: This directive works, but only if the input was changed. If the view was loaded and input untouched then still when getting this value in the controller it will be empty string instead of null. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You could simply add this at the top of the link function: `if(scope.value === '')
                  scope.value = null;`

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried but it doesn't work. `scope` does not contain `value`. Should it be some isolated scope?

Comment: In this example, it's assumed that the contextual scope contains a `value` property. As this directive simply reads one value (no assignment), it's unnecessary to make an isolate scope.