# Angular ng-model becomes an empty string after giving the input field a value and removing it again

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, string, null

input field:

```
<input  type="text" data-ng-model="some_model" />
```

The initial state of some_model is null. When I add some arbitrary value to the input field and remove it again, some_model becomes an empty string.

What I can do to solve this is something like:

```
if($scope.some_model != null && $scope.some_model != undefined && $scope.some_model.trim() == 0){
      $scope.some_model=null;
  }
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there is a standard angular way of doing this?

Comment: In your controller do you have the model set? You might/could have a default on the model.

Comment: The model is retrieved from the backend in the controller. So if it's value was null in the db, it will get a default value of null. And if I don't change it, it should stay null, but this is not what is happening in the scenario described.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344368/angular-ng-model-empty-strings-should-be-null

Answer (score 0):

I created this [pen](http://codepen.io/tlombrana22/pen/MyREjW?editors=1010) to work from, seem to be getting the expected null value. Will update as needed. Feel Free to fork and plug in some of your code.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController)
  .factory('exampleService', exampleService);
ExampleController.$inject = ['$timeout'];

function ExampleController($timeout) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.text = null;
  activate();

  function activate() {
    $timeout(function() {
      if (vm.text != null && vm.text != undefined && vm.text.trim() == 0) {
        vm.text = null;
      }
      console.log(vm.text);

    }, 10);
  }
}

function exampleService() {
  var service = {
    //basic CRUD operations.
    post: post,
    get: get,
    update: update,
    remove: remove
  };
  return service;

  function post() {}

  function get() {}

  function update() {}

  function remove() {}

}
```

```html
<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.text" />
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want me to modify the code so that it shows the problem I have? Also I never used codepen, how do I save my changes?

Comment: @MeesterPatat  Negative, if there are things in your code mine is missing to better replicate the problem feel free to fork and include a link.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKWJBz?editors=1010 see the comments above function test.