# ng-model - Empty input returns null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I have this input:

```
<input ng-model="data.value" type="number" placeholder="0" value="0">
```

When I changed the input (for example to 1) and then delete it the `data.value`
holds null. I want that when I delete the input `data.value` will hold 0 as a default value.

I saw this solution:
[Angular ng-model: empty strings should be null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344368/angular-ng-model-empty-strings-should-be-null)

This is solution will work for me but I want to know if there any other solution without `$watch` or `ng-change` function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the cleanest would be to create a custom attribute directive that requires ng-model and then applies a custom parser that transforms the value to 0, which is mentioned in the solution you linked to.

Comment: But in that case it would set it to 0. If I will have some other inputs and for each input I want other default value I will need to have a lot of directives. @Strille

Comment: Who told you need lot of directive, just create a single directive and call it to all the text box's where you want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he already found the best solution

Comment: I believe when you clear an input type="number" it becomes null. In my case I have ng-min="1" and ng-max="1000" and I want clearing the field to make it invalid and trigger my validation message. Do you think I should try to use ng-change and manually set the error myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I will have some other inputs and for each input I want other default value I will need to have a lot of directives

You could have a `defaultValue` attr for the directive which would be provided while using the directive from HTML. Something like this:

```
.directive('emptyToDefault', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          defaultValue: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function(viewValue) {
                if(viewValue === null) {
                    return scope.defaultValue || 0;
                }
                return viewValue;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Now you can easily pass different default values from outside and it will be set when string is emptied.

HTML would be like,

```
<input ng-model="data.value" type="number" placeholder="0" value="0" 
       empty-to-default default-value="5">
```

[**working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/6AhIJVW0NLgPTGPa0zcq?p=preview) (open console to notice how it sets default value `5` since string is emptied and passed value is `5`)

Answer (score 2):

> This is solution will work for me but I want to know if there any other solution without $watch

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344368/angular-ng-model-empty-strings-should-be-null) what you found, also had a solution with using `$watch`

---

If you want to use `ng-change`

Jus try this

```
<input ng-model="data.value" type="number" ng-change="defaultValue()" 
placeholder="0" value="0">
```

// controller

```
$scope.defaultValue=function()
{
  if($scope.data.value==null || $scope.data.value==='')
  {
    $scope.data.value=0;
  }
}
```

- **But `Directive` is one of the best way than other options**